# select top 5 from group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this list of transactions ordered by the client# then transaction date. What I would like to is have a list just like this except only pick the first 5 transactions per client#. If anyone can tell me how to do this I'd really appreciate it!

[image: Transaction list example]

I'm using sql server 2012

Comment: Don't post images of text. Put it in the question **as text**.

Comment: ROW_COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY something ORDER BY something) AS Something WHERE Something <= 5

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Window Function` `Dense_RANK()`

```
SELECT
 dt.client_no, dt.Last_Mdt, dt.price, dt.Tax_1, dt.Cashier
FROM(
SELECT client_no, Last_Mdt, price, Tax_1, Cashier,
      DENSE_RANK () OVER       (PARTITION BY client_no ORDER BY Last_Mdt ASC) AS Rank  
 FROM  Table
)dt 
WHERE dt.Rank <=5
```

Comment: Dense_RANK() worked perfectly thank you! I'd up vote this but apparently my reputation is not high enough.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use cross/outer apply operator for this kind of stuff. You can choose cross / outer apply and can do order by as per your requirement.

```
SELECT k.* 
FROM Table a
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 5 *
    FROM Table b
    WHERE a.client_no = b.client_no
    ORDER BY b.Last_Mdt ASC 
)k
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option using `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT yt.client_no, ca.Last_Mdt, ca.price, ca.Tax_1, ca.Cashier
FROM YourTable yt
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 5 *
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE client_no = yt.client_no
             ORDER BY Last_Mdt ASC) ca
```

Alternatively if you have a client table as well. Where presumably `client_no` is already unique.

```
SELECT yct.client_no, ca.Last_Mdt, ca.price, ca.Tax_1, ca.Cashier
FROM YourClientTable yct
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 5 *
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE client_no = yt.client_no
             ORDER BY Last_Mdt ASC) ca
```